# about spring Bean Factory Post Processors

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

How to configure `BeanFactoryPostProcessors` (like `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`) in 100 percent code based Spring environment without using `xml` file?

i have configured through xml by using context:property-placeholder tag but when it comes to 100 percent code approach i want to eliminate xml file so i configured user defined class using stereotype annotation and i linked them with Configuration class by using @ComponentScan but i dont know how to configure this BeanFactoryPostProcessors.So this is my doubt.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work before you start getting downvotes.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. What have you tried so far? Show some code that you have written.

Comment: Please move your comments to your question. That’s where they belong. It’s not about votes. It’s about finding the best answer possible. Just click on the edit button.

Comment: Just declare a `public static` method annotated with `@Bean` to register a `PropertySourcePlaceHolderConfigurer` and use `@PropertySource` to load the configuration.